# Email notification in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry

I need a code that can catch notifications when any new emails come in my Blackberry handset.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [net.rim.blackberry.api.mail.Service API](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0.2api/net/rim/blackberry/api/mail/Service.html).

Simply register with addServiceListener, and listen for folderUpdated messages.